# Steps to think of while trying to increase accuracy of network

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

How do you proceed to increasing accuracy of your neural network?

I have tried lots of architectures yet in my image detection ( classification + localization ) I can only get 75% accuracy.

I am using VOC2007 dataset, and I extracted only data where 1 person is present.

What are the steps I can think of to increase the accuracy of my object detector?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my masters thesis [Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf), chapter 2.5 page 15:

> A machine learning developer has the following choices to improve the model’s quality:
>   (I1) Change the problem definition (e.g., the classes which are to be distinguished)
>   (I2) Get more training data
>   (I3) Clean the training data
>   (I4) Change the preprocessing (see Appendix B.1)
>   (I5) Augment the training data set (see Appendix B.2)
>   (I6) Change the training setup (see Appendices B.3 to B.5)
>   (I7) Change the model (see Appendices B.6 and B.7)

It's always good to check thoroughly where exactly the problem is and compare it with a human baseline. Reliably getting better than a human is super hard.